# Multiple Java Consumers for an Action

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-8, consumer

Is there a way I can have the following action actually be two actions in one?

```
static int process(String[] cmd, File dir, Consumer<? super String> action) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    pb.directory(dir);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    Process p = pb.start();
    int exit = -1;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
        br.lines().forEach(action);
    } finally {
        log.debug("Ending process {} with exist code {} in time {}", pb.command(),
                exit = p.destroyForcibly().exitValue(), sw);
    }
    return exit;
}
```

So the `Consumer<? super String> action` I typically specify it to be `log::debug` or a custom function like `AtomicReference::set` however what if I wanted to be both, or a third? How can I have the action perform a few independent actions?

I know I could just create a custom `Consumer` that does whatever I want, but I think it would be very convenient
 if I could almost treat the action like an nvarargs equivalent, but for functions/actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few alternatives here, some of which have already been mention by others.

Perhaps the most lambda like approach would be to use the consumers own aggregation method `andThen` (defined in `Consumer` itself):

```
Stream<X> exes = ....
exes.forEach(action1
    .andThen(action2)
    .andThen(action3)
    .andThen(...)
    .andThen(actionN));
```

Where all `action?` are declared as `Consumer<X>` or `Consumer<? super X>`.

Without looking at the docs to confirm. I guess that actions 1 to N are executed one right after the other on the same thread for every element in the stream.

Another possibility here is to use `peek` that basically passes the elements of the stream to an action without consuming them as it returns a stream that would contain the same elements.

```
Stream<X> exes = ...
exes.peek(action1)
 .peek(action2)
 .peek(action3)
 .peek(...)
 .forEach(actionN);
```

Without looking at the docs I bet that:

- you need to actually call to a final consuming action like `forEach` (or `count`, `empty`, etc.) in order to get the different peeks executed.
- that the only restriction in execution order is that action-i will go before action-j for any given element in the stream as long as i < j. No other assumption can be made unless we know something else about the stream (is it parallel/serial, sorted, etc.).

I reckon that you may want to use `Consumer.andThen` based on the content of your question however `peek` seems like a plausible solution if there is some action whose execution is not central/main to the task at hand but rather like a desirable side-effect.

Perhaps you want to pass a modified stream that would "spy" on what objects are being processed later by the code that the stream reference has been passed to. In that case `peek` is the better if not the only option.

Of course you could also do a combination of both.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy enough to make a `Consumer` that delegates to other consumers.  You just write

```
 str -> {
   action1(str);
   action2(str);
   // etc
 }
```

since you don't *have* to use method references, you can always use lambdas.  Writing your `Consumer` in that style also tends to be more readable than trying to combine them in other ways, though other ways are possible.